# How can I change the default create view code generated by resharper via the "View action list -> create view"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, resharper-5.0

I am using Resharper 5, I like to create views by clicking on the red lightbulb then choose Create View from the action list (for example screenshot see https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CyEM.png).

Does anyone know if there is a "Create View" template that i can edit to change the default generated code? I'd like to put in things such as custom namespaces etc but cant figure out how to do it.

I have looked into live templates but it seems to be totally different to what i want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `ReSharper | Live Templates | <template type>`. Then from template explorer, you can edit existing templates.

[Documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Index.html) here.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help but I dont think this is what I am after.
How does it know to override the "Create View" command in the action list?

Comment: I dont have any predefined mvc templates at all nor am i using Razor so i dont know where resharper is getting the template code from.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those come predefined with Resharper. See this: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Template_Basics__Applicability_and_Storage_of_Templates.html